# Trying to use package, require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just installed: `npm i node-id3`, from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-id3. Ironically, I am unable to use this package. I am running on **Node.js v18.14.0**.

According to the link:

```
const NodeID3 = require('node-id3')
NodeID3.read(file, function(err, tags) {})
```

This leads to this:

```
const NodeID3 = require('node-id3')
                ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\root\Documents\GitHub\Database\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Comment: do you have "type": "module" in package.json

Comment: @cmgchess, what do you mean?

Comment: ur project has a package.json . check if there is a field called type with value module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is telling you that Node is using ES modules because in your `package.json` the `type` property is set to `module`

[Node.js has two module systems](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules): CommonJS modules and ECMAScript modules.

CommonJS uses `require` and ES modules use `import`

```js
// commmonjs
const NodeID3 = require('node-id3');

// ES modules
import NodeID3 from 'node-id3';
```

You have a few options:

- if you want to keep using ESM, change your `require` to an `import`
- to use CommonJS, either remove the line `type: "module"` from your package.json or change the extension of your javascript file from `.js` to `.cjs` to instruct node to treat it as a CommonJS script